# Correct way with in_array

Tags: php

I have a problem with in_array giving me a notice: undefined index.

```
if ( 
   ($value['device'] == $this->device or $value['device'] == 'all')
     and
   (!is_array($value['excludeLang']) or !in_array($this->lang, $value['excludeLang']))
    and
   ($value['site'] == $this->site or $value['site'] == 'all')
            ) {

                // do something

            }
```

In this case $value['excludeLang'] is not an array. Is there a way of suppressing the error when I check if $this->lang is in the array

Comment: isset() is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(!isset($value['excludeLang']) or !is_array($value['excludeLang']) or !in_array($this->lang, $value['excludeLang']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `isset()`, specifically with your example I'd write it as follows:

```
if (
    ($value['device'] == $this->device or $value['device'] == 'all')
      and
    (!isset($value['excludeLang']) or !is_array($value['excludeLang']) or !in_array($this->lang, $value['excludeLang']))
      and
    ($value['site'] == $this->site or $value['site'] == 'all')
    ) {

        // do something

    }
```

The reason this works, and I think it's important to bear this in mind, is because of the way `||` (or) conditions are evaluated in PHP.

Take the condition

```
if ($condition1 || $condition2)
```

Only one thing in an `or` statement needs to be evaluated as being `true`. PHP is evaluated left to right, and so in this case if `$condition1` is evaluated as true, PHP won't bother to check `$condition2`.

In your specific case, if `!isset($value['excludeLang'])` is evaluated as being `true`, it will never get as far as trying to run `in_array`, it will skip all the other conditions, return `true` and continue.